# proof for the probability$P(A^{c}\cup C)$.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $A,B,C$ be pair-wise independent (like A and B are independent) such that$P(A^{c}\cap B)=0.1$ and $P(B\cap C)=0.2$ Show that $P(A^{c}\cup C)\ge \frac{7}{8}$.

$P(A^{c}\cup C)=1-P(C^{c}\cap A)\\=1-P(C^{c})\cdot P(A)$ 
what can i do next and how can I use the given information.
I know $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)=0.1\text{and}\ P(B\cap C)=P(B)\cdot P(C)=0.2\\ 2P(A)=P(C)$

Comment: $P(C)=0.2$ and $P(A^c)=0.1$ fit the given data, but $P(A^c \cup C)\le 0.3$ in this case, so something is missing. Perhaps a restriction on $P(B)$.

Answer (score 2):

You are given that $P(A^c\cap B)=P(A^c)P(B)=0.1$ and that $P(C\cap B)=P(C)P(B)=0.2$ which you can combine (as you almost have done by yourself) to obtain that $$P(C)=2P(A^c)$$ From this you can also deduce that $$0.2=P(B\cap C)\le P(C)=2P(A^c)\tag{1}$$

So, 
\begin{align}P(A^c\cup C)&=P(A^c)+P(C)-P(A^c\cap C)\\&=P(A^c)+P(C)-P(A^c)P(C)=P(A^c)+2P(A^c)-2P(A^c)^2\\&=3P(A^c)-2P(A^c)^2\\&=P(A^c)(3-2P(A^c))\end{align} Denote $p:=P(A^c)$ and your task is equivalent to show that $$p(3-2p)\ge \frac78$$ which is true for $0.4\le p\le 1$. However from the given data, see $(1)$, you only have that $p\ge 0.1$ which is not enough.